# BCP outputs 'NULL' after running the query

Tags: sql, t-sql, bcp

I've been searching for the answer to this problem and could not find anything so far.

When executing bcp command with a query, I'm getting `NULL` as an output.

However, when executing the query by itself, everything looks good.

First, I thought, that may be my query has errors, but after it executed successfully, I got more confused.

So, here is my code executing bcp command:

```
DECLARE @query VARCHAR(2000)
DECLARE @bcpCommand VARCHAR(1024)
DECLARE @sharedDevFolder VARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @environment VARCHAR(5)
DECLARE @customerCode VARCHAR(5)
DECLARE @parserConfig VARCHAR(5)
DECLARE @bucketAssign VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @dateFormat VARCHAR(15)
DECLARE @input INT
DECLARE @RC INT

SET @sharedDevFolder = '\\REMOTESERVER\Data'
SET @input = 201507
SET @fileName = 'Transaction-' + 
                @environment + '-' + 
                @customerCode + '-' + 
                @parserConfig + '-' + 
                @bucketAssign + '-' + 
                @dateFormat + '.txt'

SET @query = 'SELECT ''Transaction Unique ID'', ''Transaction Date'', ''Person Unique ID'' UNION ALL SELECT NULL AS ''Transaction Unique ID'', CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CONVERT(DATETIME,Date,1),101) AS ''Transaction Date'', NULL AS ''Person Unique ID'' FROM tblChromeRiverInitData WHERE YYYYMM = ' + CAST(@input as VARCHAR)

select @query

--need to change @sharedDevFolder depending on a server environment
SET @bcpCommand = 'bcp "' + @query + '" queryout "'
set @bcpCommand = @bcpCommand + @sharedDevFolder + @fileName + '" -c -T -t^| -r\n'

EXEC @RC = master..xp_cmdshell @bcpCommand
```

And here is my query by itself:

```
DECLARE @input INT
SET @input = 201507
SELECT 'Transaction Unique ID','Transaction Date', 'Person Unique ID' UNION ALL SELECT NULL AS 'Transaction Unique ID', CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CONVERT(DATETIME,Date,1),101) AS 'Transaction Date', NULL AS 'Person Unique ID' FROM tblChromeRiverInitData WHERE YYYYMM = @input
```

This query executes fine.

I'm not sure where to look from now on.

Comment: does your client have `write` access on the `\\REMOTESERVER\Data` folder?

Comment: Yes, I have already executed almost the same code through stored procedure and it created a file for me. I just decided to change the logic and write the query inline. Before, I had to create a table where I insert all the fields as the first row and `UNION ALL` with the data itself to make sure that my file has column headers. Now, I decided to change the logic and do everything inline without creating a table. And I'm getting the described results

Comment: okay..have you tried with `servername`, `username` and `password` parameters instead of using a `trusted connection` parameter?

Comment: Actually, trusted connection worked just fine in stored proc

Comment: i faced the same issue a few days ago and i tried out this option and it worked for me.

Comment: We use trusted connections when run bcps. We are not connecting to other networs

Comment: Tried using trusted connection, even though, I think I do not need it. The result is the same. Nothing works so far. SO, probably, there is something else